# ASP.NET + IIS 7 - URL Rewriting

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have an index site. On every index there are sub-categories and different cities.
Today my URLs look like this:
~/index.aspx?indexid=1&catid=2&location=4

I want to rewrite this to:
~/party-planning-birthday-parties-new-york
Where indexid=1 is an index named Party Planning,
catid=2 is a sub-category called "birthday parties"
etc.

What would be the best way of going about this?
And a small side question: Do you think this is a good rewriting scheme?
I think it makes the URLs much more readable and informative.

Thank you!
-Elad

Comment: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite ?

Comment: Yep. That was what I was looking for. Care to write that as an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)  Added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is an official solution on the official IIS developer community page:

http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Never used it myself - I've only used their older sample code (which worked well enough for my purposes).

Comment: This really allows any kind of rewriting scheme. Surprisingly well implemented.